# Pixel Values in OpenCV exceeds 255 - 1D Histogram

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

http://www.huahongquan.com/index.php/blog/x-ly-nh-video-s/11-opencv-topic-02-get-histogram

I used his code to calculate 1D histograms for my images. The problem is, the range is set from 0-255 but I when I print the values, I get pixel values that exceed 255 (ie 15842, 73132)

Is there something I need to add with the code?

@George this is how I print the values and I use Mat.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++){
cout << "Value"  << i << " = " << histogram.at<float>(i) << endl;        
}
```

Comment: What code do you use to print the values? If you just use C++ IO stream, it's possible that you need typecasting to define that the data are `unsigned char` and not `int`. Of course the IplImage must have color depth of `IPL_DEPTH_8U`, otherwise it's natural that the values are so big.

Comment: @GeorgeAprilis thanks but I've converted them to grayscale. How I print the values is above (I edited my Q) thanks!

Comment: so you mean it worked now with the conversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the range 0-255 you say is the number of bins, not the pixel value.

The `histogram.at<float>(i)` is the number of pixels that fall into bin `i`, so it can be any integer ranging from 0 to the size of the input image (width * height).

For example, the output `Value254 = 4182` means there are 4182 pixels whose values are 254.